# Infinite Scroll with shuffle results

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, infinite-scroll

How do I return random results that do not repeat?

For example, I've an infinite scrolling page, every time I get to the bottom it returns ten results, but sometimes the results are repeated.

I'm using this query to get results:

`SELECT TOP 10 * FROM table_name ORDER BY NEWID()`

Sorry, I don't know if you'll understand.

Comment: I think you are looking for pagination, but if your scrolling is infinite and your database is not, there will be duplicates.

Comment: In order to generate a separate 10 rows each time, which are (pseudo-)randomly selected from the table, you will need to remember where you are "up to" or currently located within the set. For example, if you want to generate  the third set of 10 rows, you need to know which 20 to exclude from your result. You can't do this with a single SQL statement. You will need some external variable to hold the current position/state. You also need a way to select rows which *seems* random, but is actually predictable.

Comment: The rows can be ordered by a seeded rand() function. When the user needs more result the same seed is used. See my answer for an example. Whether it is the correct solution or not depends on OPs definition of "infinite scroll".

Comment: How large is your table?

Answer (score 0):

When you call the query from your application you set the seed for the RAND() function.

```
SET @rand = RAND(your_seed); -- initialize RAND with the seed.
SELECT * FROM table_name
ORDER BY RAND() -- Calls to RAND should now be based on the seed
OFFSET 0 LIMIT 10 -- use some MsSQL equivalent here ;)
```

(not tested)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, `NEWID()` has known distributional problems.  Although random, the numbers sometimes cluster together.  This would account for what you are seeing.  You could try this:

```
SELECT TOP 10 *
FROM table_name
ORDER BY rand(checksum(NEWID()));
```

This may give you a better results.

The real answer, though, is to use a seeded pseudo-random number generator.  Basically, enumerate the rows of the table *and store the value in the table*.  Or calculate it in a deterministic way.  Then do simple math to choose a row:

```
with t as (
      select t.*, row_number() over (order by id) as seqnum,
             count(*) over () as cnt
      from table_name
     )
select t.*
from t
where mod(seqnum * 74873, cnt) = 13907;
```

The numbers are just two prime numbers, which ensure a lack of cycles.

EDIT:

Here is a more complete solution to your problem:

```
with t as (
      select t.*, row_number() over (order by id) as seqnum,
             count(*) over () as cnt
      from table_name
     )
select t.*
from t
where mod(seqnum * 74873 + 13907, cnt) <= 10;
```

Or whatever the limits are.  The idea is that using a large prime number for the multiplicative factor makes it highly likely (but not 100% certain) that that cnt and "74783" are what is called "mutually prime" or "coprime".  This means that the pseudo-random number generator just described will rearrange the sequence numbers and you can just use comparisons to get a certain number of rows.  This is part of mathematics called Number Theory.

Comment: Before your answer I tried this:  SELECT TOP 10 * FROM table_name WHERE id NOT IN ($ids_from_other_querys) ORDER BY NEWID() It works fine. What you think about this way? It the best way?

Comment: (1) It requires storing all the previous ids, which is additional overhead.  (2) As the number of used ids increases, the performance will degrade.  (3) It will work better if the table is dynamic while this process is running.

Comment: I don't understand this part on your code `where mod(seqnum * 74873, cnt) = 13907;` and how I'll limit the results to 10?